# Error in converting TensorType(float32, matrix) to TensorType(int32, matrix)

Tags: python, matrix, theano

I have written a code for a Deep Learning Algorithm. However I am stuck just in the final stage of loading the data.

```
self.x = T.imatrix("x")
self.y = T.ivector("y")
```

are defined as the variables which hold the data

then I do

```
train_x, train_y, train_lengths = dataUtils.read_and_sort_matlab_data(path+"train.txt",path+"train_lbl.txt")
validate_x, validate_y, validate_lengths = dataUtils.read_and_sort_matlab_data(path+"valid.txt",path+"valid_lbl.txt")
tested_x, tested_y, tested_lengths = dataUtils.read_and_sort_matlab_data(path+"test.txt",path+"test_lbl.txt")
```

Here I have checked the types of variables
train_y is of type numpy.ndarray with shape(2000,)
and train_y[0] is of type 'int32'.

then I put the data into theano shared variables

```
training_x,training_y = shared(train_x,train_y)
validation_x,validation_y = shared(validate_x,validate_y)
test_x,test_y = shared(tested_x,tested_y)
```

where the shared function is defined as follows

```
def shared(data_x,data_y):

    shared_x = theano.shared(np.asarray(data_x, dtype=theano.config.floatX), borrow=True)
    shared_y = theano.shared(np.asarray(data_y, dtype=theano.config.floatX), borrow=True)
    return shared_x, T.cast(shared_y, "int32")
```

I get the error in the following code

```
train_mb = theano.function(
            [i], cost, updates=updates,
            givens={
                self.x:
                training_x[i*self.document_length: (i+1)*self.document_length],
                self.y:
                training_y[i: (i+1)]
            })
```

At line

```
training_y[i: (i+1)]
```

And the error is

TypeError: Cannot convert Type TensorType(float32, matrix) (of Variable Subtensor{int64:int64:}.0) into Type TensorType(int32, matrix). You can try to manually convert Subtensor{int64:int64:}.0 into a TensorType(int32, matrix).

Can someone tell where is the float32 being introduced when I have already cast the shared_y variable?? And how to correct this error. Also why are there matrices in the error statement when train_y is a vector as suggested ny its shape??

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It is actually the training_x bit which was giving the error not the training_y.